# How to add a PayPal button to a customer's website

Tags: paypal

I'm developing a website.And the client wants to add PayPal button on it.
He has bussiness acount with PayPal.

So, My question is - what is the procedure ?

Must I ask him to login with his account, create a button and send me the html code? He is not familiar with web-development at all!

And is it OK to ask him to provide me his `PayPal credentials` in order to do all that staff by myself ?

What is the common approach here?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to integration of PayPal button [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/)

Answer (score 0):

You may check below code as a simple sample.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR_PAYPAL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="#1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
</form>
```

For more details of each variable, please refer to below page.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/